# passing dynamic id's to javascript

Tags: javascript

i have a while loop that changes the id of each input field.

```
   print"<td><input style=\"text-align:center\" type=text name=productitemsupdate_$num value=\"$row[productitems]\" size=5 id=pro$num>}</td>"; <-- this should produce pro0
```

above if i have 3 orders i should have 3 ids

id- pro0
id- pro1
id- pro2

in my javascript i want to call the id's like so

```
var pro = form.pro0.value;

  if(pro == "") {

  inlineMsg('pro','You can\'t leave this blank.',10);

  return false;

  }
```

the problem is the value does not work.

It works with single variables like passing things outside the loop but when i want to send the id's from within the loop they do not work. can anyone help

many thanks

kardklub

Comment: Does the fields actually have these IDs or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`form.pro0.value;`

is used to access input with name as `pro0`

Try `form.productitemsupdate_0.value` or

try using `getElementById` http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-getelementbyid.php

Also change your php code to

```
print"<td><input style=\"text-align:center\" type=\"text\" name=\"productitemsupdate_$num\" value=\"$row[productitems]\" size=\"5\" id=\"pro$num\">}</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use square bracket notation instead of dot notation.

```
foo.bar === foo['bar']
```

You can pass the string in a variable rather than as a literal.

Comment: Err. The example is quite simple. Use a string in square brackets instead of an identifier prefixed by a dot.